# ConcurrentModificationException upon committing transaction with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In our application we have upgraded from Hibernate 3.5.6-final to 4.2.21.Final and now we are getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` when a database transaction is committed:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
```

Is this a known issue with Hibernate 4.2?

Comment: have you used Entity event listeners do some custom work (pre persit or post persist)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exception turned out to be caused by a problem with a Hibernate custom constraint validator we use. The validator's `isValid` was running a Hibernate criteria query. The query triggered a Hibernate session flush which resulted in the `ConcurrentModificationException`. We fixed the problem by temporarily disabling auto flush in the `isValid` method:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(Object object, final ConstraintValidatorContext c) {
   try {
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
      ...
   } finally {
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.AUTO);
   }
}
```

The problem may also manifest itself as a `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 3):

I had this with hibernate 5.0.11 and verified it happened also with 5.2.5. My solution was to annotate the custom validator to open new transaction.

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

I guess hibernate has still some way to go before custom constraint validators are made easy to setup and use since this took me way more time than it should.

Edit: Issue related. I think using the same transaction violates jpa2.1 specs https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7537

Answer (score 1):

In the class which implements a ConstraintValidator, we need to have an instance of EntityManager but we are not in a Spring context in order to instanciate automatically an EntityManager object with annotation @Autowired. So, in the configuration package, we can write a factory wich allows to have an instance of Application in order to instanciate beans when we are not in a Spring context.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationContextConf {

    @Bean
    public static ApplicationContextProvider contextProvider() {
        return new ApplicationContextProvider();
    }

}
```

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
}
```

In the class which implements a ConstraintValidator, we instanciate an EntityManager thanks to the factory created previously in the method initialize.

Before to call to a method which calls the repository, we change the flush mode of the Hibernate current session to FlushMode.MANUAL in order to avoid having the automatic flush after the call to the repository while keeping the default flush mode. In the block finally, we restore the default value of the flush mode previously retained.

```
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public void initialize(final Object object ) {
    // ...

    try {
        this.entityManager = ApplicationContextConf
                .contextProvider()
                    .getApplicationContext()
                    .getBean(EntityManager.class);
    }
    catch (final BeansException ex) {
    // ...
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(final Object object, final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    Session hibernateSession = null;
    FlushMode originalFlushMode = null;

    try {
        hibernateSession = this.entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        originalFlushMode = hibernateSession.getFlushMode();
        hibernateSession.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);

        // ...
    }
    finally {
        if (hibernateSession != null) {
            hibernateSession.setFlushMode(originalFlushMode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to indent you code (at minimum) 4 spaces to format it as such.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer as well.